# JavaScript: How to restore file from file's content?

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets, download

**Hi!**

I've got a web application and I have to send some encrypted files from browser (client-side) to a server and then I have to download (in another browser), decrypt and save those files. I work with HTML + JS (front-end) and with Java/Servlets/Tomcat (back-end).

I already got it to send a file from JavaScript to my servlet (via FormData) and store that file on disk, but I have a problem to sending that file back to the browser.

I can't directly download the file from the server through a link because those files are supposed to be encrypted, so, before store them to local disk, I have to decrypt them.

I was able to send the content of a file from servlet to browser and even restore files like .txt and .csv, but I am not able to restore images (for example).

**Code from servlet**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("image/png");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"licitatie_raluca.png\"");
        File srcFile = new File("../../Programe/eclipse/workspace/FileUploadingTest/WebContent/uplfiles/licitatie_raluca.png");
        FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, response.getOutputStream());
    }
```

**Code from JavaScript**

```
var content;
function download() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "FileDownloader",
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                    success : function(result) {
                        /* Create the link for downloading the file */
                        content = result;
                        getFile();
                    }
                });
            }

function getFile() {
    var download = function(content, fileName, mimeType) {
        alert(content);
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        mimeType = mimeType || 'application/octet-stream';

        if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE10
            return navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([content], { type: mimeType }), fileName);
        } else if ('download' in a) { //html5 A[download]
            a.href = 'data:' + mimeType + ',' + encodeURIComponent(content);
            a.setAttribute('download', fileName);
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            setTimeout(function() {
                a.click();
                document.body.removeChild(a);
            }, 66);
            return true;
        } else { //do iframe dataURL download (old ch+FF):
            var f = document.createElement('iframe');
            document.body.appendChild(f);
            f.src = 'data:' + mimeType + ',' + encodeURIComponent(content);

            setTimeout(function() {
                document.body.removeChild(f);
            }, 333);
            return true;
        }
    }
    download(content, "imgage.png", "image/png");   
}
```

**EDIT NO. 1**

For the moment I don't have the implementation of encryption/decryption because  I want to do the file transfer between browser-server first and then server-browser.

When I was trying to create the .png file from the content received from servlet, I was able to "create" and save it, but when I tried to open it I got an error: "Fatal error reading PNG image file: Not a PNG file".

**EDIT NO. 2**
I can restore only the files that contain plaintext. I'm not able to restore files like .png, .pdf. When I try to restore a .pdf file I get the file but I only have empty pages...

**Thank you!**

Comment: What is error or exception you get while sending image files? Also upload a snapshot of code encryption or decryption code so that we can help better..

Comment: I will edit my post to provide those information. Thank you!